# Vanity URL in PHP and htaccess keeps redirecting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to write a vanity URL redirect system but keep getting hit with a "Too many redirects error"

My htaccess currently looks like this...

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect to domain without www.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Same for HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Vanity URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /vanity.php?page=$1
```

The htaccess redirects the user to a page called vanity.php which then processes the page. It looks like this...

```
<?php
$page = htmlspecialchars($_GET['page']);
header("Location: " . $page . ".php");
?>
```

What I believe is happening is that the htaccess is looping it back to vanity.php everytime vanity.php redirects it to the correct page. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by that redirect from within your PHP script in the first place? This appears to make rather little sense.

Comment: That PHP file detects what page the viewer is trying to access then displays the page info from the database.

Comment: But why are you _redirecting_? Let’s say you requested the URL `/foobar`, then that will first be rewritten internally to `/vanity.php?page=foobar`. And them from that, you externally redirect to `foobar.php` again - external redirect meaning, this will be what the browser address bar will show. Is _that_ what you call a “vanity URL”?